# how to make a File upload form with one input in PHP?

Tags: php, html, file-upload

My question is straightforward, i want my Form to be just an input button to browse for the  file and do the work too instead of two inputs like in the image bellow :
here is my code :

**EDIT : ** all I want is ONE BUTTON not two like in the picture , one button to do the work preferably called "upload image" 
in the image bellow the form consists of two buttons one does the choosing and another one does the submitting of the form action.

```
<form class='formUpload' action="uploadImage.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input value="Upload Image" class="ToUpload" name="fileToUpload" type="file" />
   <input type="submit" name="fileToUpload" value="Upload Image">
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: so you want the upload to happen as soon as they choose a file, am I right? If so, that's not a very good idea. What if they chose the wrong file, one being of: *ahem*... well you know and for other reasons also. I would rethink this.

Comment: not exactly happen but i want the form to submit the $_POST so i can handle it in the 'uploadImage.php' file

Comment: post / edit your question as per what's inside uploadImage.php - if this is about just uploading, then see the manual on that http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php - TBH, I'm not quite sure what you're asking.

Comment: its not about the upload its about this : i want one button labelled "upload image" JUST ONE BUTTON not two( one for the choosing and one for submitting the form action )

Comment: so you don't want the "Choose File", correct? If so, you can't avoid that. Sorry, but you'll have to see if anyone knows something I don't.

Comment: if i am not wrong and if you are open to use jquery then you can use jquery Change() function to get the behavior you are asking for....and yes you have to manually post the form in that case..

Comment: I just started learning php last week, I don't know about jQuery but if its no complicated I'd appreciate the help

Comment: @NeoMosaid its ok i you can do it with javascript as well as jquery provides some direct methods asked about it..rest posted a demo jquery based eg try it...hope that helps...:D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok let me add an example asumming you are expecting the same here is something that you might be looking:

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="abc.php" name="imageform" id="imageform">
Choose File :<input type="file" name="file" id='fileupload'>
</form>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#fileupload').on('change',function(){
      $('#imageform').submit();
   });
});
```

Comment: I tried it , it should work as the script causes the form to submit upon the selection of the file to upload, but its not working and i'm sure i change it to fit the id of the form and submit button in my code !!

Comment: have you included jquery files?? just asking..? if so what error you can see...have you checked console for any errors?

Comment: i'm not sure what to include i included this : `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` and the form is submitting but $_POST is sent empty and not isset

Comment: ok..you included the right files....as you said form is submitting..also i tried the same code and received the image name on other end...can you add your snippet here..

Comment: here is something http://pastebin.com/ZTVFSY64 also a suggestion as you are storing base64 encoded image in database is not suggested as it will add burden on server.;..rather save file in folder and its path in database...:D

Comment: still same error : Post error ie the submission sent the $_POST empty !!

Comment: @NeoMosaid you have to check the $_FILES['name of file']..not $_POST['filename']..i tested the link code before sharing and worked for me...still if problem persist and you want help let me know on chat

Comment: @NeoMosaid Glad Helped You...Cheers :D